# Connecting to databases somee

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, somee

Connecting directly to the constructor to the database located on somee.com. On the local machine works. Once deployed on somee.com, do not connect to the database.

```
    public LazyToDoContext()
        : base("workstation id=LazyToDo.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=UserId;pwd=Password;data source=LazyToDo.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=LazyToDo")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Bad connection string / Firewall / Incorrect configuration - choose one

Comment: show, what error do you get. add more information

Comment: @lad2025  locally everything works on the same connection string.

Comment: @Backs where a logs on the somee?

Comment: Are you saying you don't get an error message? How do you know it can't connect to the database? Help us to help you by providing some information.

Comment: @SeanLange server responding with a status of 500 on the ajax-requests

Comment: so it might be a sql issue or it could be nearly anything if all you have a response code. I would check this provider and ask them how to debug errors on their server.